# How to find all characters except anything in between two square brackets

Tags: ms-word, wildcard

In Word, I would like to keep the text in between `[` and `]` and remove anything else. For example, using a wildcard, I would like to keep `ABC-1234` in `[ABC-1234] Lorem ipsum`.

`Lorem ipsum` could be any character. Not limited to alphanumerical characters.

There are large number of occurrences in a table. The output should keep the table format and only get rid of any text that is outside of the brackets (including the brackets).

For example,

FROM:

`[ABC-1234] Banana is yellow.`

`[ZFA-333] Apple is red.`

`[GES-95443] Blueberry is blue.`

TO:

`ABC-1234`

`ZFA-333`

`GES-95443`

Above represents each row item. However, some rows have multiple instances of these bracketed terms. They can be separated by comma if there is more than one instance in a single row.

Comment: Are you saying that when replacing/clearing, don't replace the character in between `[`and`]`? Or do you want to keep the characters between `[`and`]` and clear any characters outside the square brackets?

Comment: keep the characters between ```[``` and ```]``` and clear any characters outside the square brackets

Comment: `in a single row` or ` in a single Cell`？ Or do your tables only have a column in it?

Comment: Single cell in a row of multiple columns. I would like to simply select the entire column and find/replace. This is important because I don't want to delete the content in other columns.

Comment: Do you mean that what is in the table, though outside the square brackets, is also kept? As long as there is a square bracket in the same cell, only in these cells, will the content outside the square bracket in that cell be deleted? My current code clears everything outside the square brackets, even tables. Please think about this more carefully and don't forget something again, so that we don't have to change the code again and again.

Comment: If just like I said before then just comment out the code the two parts `clear the cells in that table` `'clear the previous cell` will be ok. If you need this, I will update my code again, or if you do this by yourself just use my latest updated code to implement it. ( already Done, see the end of my answer )

Answer (score 0):

Can I use a **regular expression** instead? Instead of using a **wildcard**. If it is acceptable, please test the following code, and if you accept this answer, please add **regex** and **vba** tags to your question. Thanks.

- **Select** the text you want to do, and run the code beloved.
- The following code is only for **plain text** processing and will not retain the original **format of the document**. Let me know if you need to keep the document in its original format.

```vb
Sub RemoveOutsideSquareBrackets()
    Dim pattern As String, match
    Dim regEx As Object
    Dim matches As Object
    Dim newText As String
    
    pattern = "\[[^\]]+\]"
    Set regEx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    
    With regEx
        .Global = True
        .IgnoreCase = False
        .pattern = pattern
    End With
    
    Rem select the text you want to do
    If regEx.test(Selection.Text) Then
        Set matches = regEx.Execute(Selection.Text)
        For Each match In matches
            'newText = newText & match & " " ' if you do want a space to separate then use this
            newText = newText & match
        Next match
        Selection.Text = Trim(newText)'plain text only
    Else
        MsgBox "No matches found."
    End If
End Sub
```

### 20230715 Wildcard and VBA

> ... I have a complex table in a Word document and I am not able to move it to another editor where I can run regex. It has to be wildcard. And yes I have to keep the original document format.

> I tried your code. This keeps the brackets. I only want to keep what is between the brackets. Not the brackets themselves.

> some rows have multiple instances of these bracketed terms. They can be separated by comma if there is more than one instance in a single row.

> There are large number of occurrences in a table. The output should keep the table format and only get rid of any text that is outside of the brackets (including the brackets).

This will do the active document content no matter the selection.

```vb
Sub KeepTextBetweenBracketsInDocument()
    Dim rng As Range, d As Document, s As Long, rngDel As Range, e As Long, c As Cell, ur As UndoRecord, rngPre As Range, cl As Cell
    Set d = ActiveDocument: Set ur = Word.Application.UndoRecord
    Set rng = d.Range: Set rngDel = d.Range
    s = 0
    ur.StartCustomRecord "KeepTextBetweenBracketsInDocument"
    With rng.Find
        .ClearAllFuzzyOptions
        .ClearFormatting
        .Text = "[[]*[]]"
        .MatchWildcards = True
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        While .Execute
            e = rng.Start
            rngDel.SetRange s, e
            If rng.Tables.Count = 0 Then
                If Not rngPre Is Nothing Then
                    If rngPre.Information(wdWithInTable) Then
                        ' clear the cells in that table
                        Set cl = rngPre.Tables(1).Range.Cells(rngPre.Tables(1).Range.Cells.Count)
                        Do Until cl.RowIndex = rngPre.Cells(1).RowIndex And cl.ColumnIndex = rngPre.Cells(1).ColumnIndex
                            cl.Range.Text = vbNullString
                            Set cl = cl.Previous
                        Loop
                        'clear the text before
                        d.Range(rngPre.Tables(1).Range.End, rng.Start).Text = vbNullString
                    Else
                        'rngDel.Delete
                        rngDel.Text = vbNullString
                    End If
                Else
                    'rngDel.Delete
                    rngDel.Text = vbNullString
                End If
                
            'in table
            Else
                Rem in tables
'                Stop just for test
                If Not rngPre Is Nothing Then
                    If Not rngPre.Information(wdWithInTable) Then 'if previous pos in not in table
                        d.Range(rngPre.End, rng.Tables(1).Range.Start - 1).Text = vbNullString 'clear the text before the table
                        'clear the previous cell
                        Set cl = rng.Tables(1).Cell(1, 1)
                        Do Until cl.RowIndex = rng.Cells(1).RowIndex And cl.ColumnIndex = rng.Cells(1).ColumnIndex
                            cl.Range.Text = vbNullString
                            Set cl = cl.Next
                        Loop
                    End If
                End If
                e = rng.Start
                If rng.Information(wdWithInTable) Then
                    If c Is Nothing Then
                        Set c = rng.Cells(1)
                        s = c.Range.Start
                        rngDel.SetRange s, e
                        rngDel.Text = vbNullString
                    Else
                        'If c Is rng.Cells(1) Then 'in the same cell  more than one instance
                        If c.RowIndex = rng.Cells(1).RowIndex And c.ColumnIndex = rng.Cells(1).ColumnIndex Then 'in the same cell  more than one instance
                            rngDel.SetRange s, e
                            rngDel.Text = ","
                        Else
                            Set c = rng.Cells(1)
                            s = c.Range.Start
                            rngDel.SetRange s, e
                            rngDel.Text = vbNullString
                        End If
                    End If
                End If
                
            End If
            If rng.Characters(1) = "," And rng.Characters(2) = "[" Then
                rng.Characters(2) = vbNullString
            Else
                rng.Characters(1) = vbNullString
            End If
            rng.Characters(rng.Characters.Count) = vbNullString
            s = rng.End
            Set rngPre = rng.Duplicate
        Wend
        d.Range(rng.End, d.Range.End - 1).Text = vbNullString
    End With
    ur.EndCustomRecord

End Sub
```

> ...I would like to simply select the entire column and find/replace. This is important because I don't want to delete the content in other columns.

> Do you mean that what is in the table, though outside the square brackets, is also kept? As long as there is a square bracket in the same cell, only in these cells, will the content outside the square bracket in that cell be deleted?...

> If just like I said before then just comment out the code the two parts clear the cells in that table 'clear the previous cell will be ok. If you need this, I will update my code again, or if you do this by yourself just use my latest updated code to implement it.

Like this:

```vb
Rem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76688687/how-to-find-all-characters-except-anything-in-between-two-square-brackets/76689206#76689206
Sub KeepTextBetweenBracketsInDocument()
    Dim rng As Range, d As Document, s As Long, rngDel As Range, e As Long, c As Cell, ur As UndoRecord, rngPre As Range, cl As Cell
    Set d = ActiveDocument: Set ur = Word.Application.UndoRecord
    Set rng = d.Range: Set rngDel = d.Range
    s = 0
    ur.StartCustomRecord "KeepTextBetweenBracketsInDocument"
    With rng.Find
        .ClearAllFuzzyOptions
        .ClearFormatting
        .Text = "[[]*[]]"
        .MatchWildcards = True
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        While .Execute
            e = rng.Start
            rngDel.SetRange s, e
            If rng.Tables.Count = 0 Then
                If Not rngPre Is Nothing Then
                    If rngPre.Information(wdWithInTable) Then
'                        ' clear the cells in that table
'                        Set cl = rngPre.Tables(1).Range.Cells(rngPre.Tables(1).Range.Cells.Count)
'                        Do Until cl.RowIndex = rngPre.Cells(1).RowIndex And cl.ColumnIndex = rngPre.Cells(1).ColumnIndex
'                            cl.Range.Text = vbNullString
'                            Set cl = cl.Previous
'                        Loop
                        'clear the text before
                        d.Range(rngPre.Tables(1).Range.End, rng.Start).Text = vbNullString
                    Else
                        'rngDel.Delete
                        rngDel.Text = vbNullString
                    End If
                Else
                    'rngDel.Delete
                    rngDel.Text = vbNullString
                End If
                
            'in table
            Else
                Rem in tables
'                Stop just for test
                If Not rngPre Is Nothing Then
                    If Not rngPre.Information(wdWithInTable) Then 'if previous pos in not in table
                        d.Range(rngPre.End, rng.Tables(1).Range.Start - 1).Text = vbNullString 'clear the text before the table
'                        'clear the previous cell
'                        Set cl = rng.Tables(1).Cell(1, 1)
'                        Do Until cl.RowIndex = rng.Cells(1).RowIndex And cl.ColumnIndex = rng.Cells(1).ColumnIndex
'                            cl.Range.Text = vbNullString
'                            Set cl = cl.Next
'                        Loop
                    End If
                End If
                e = rng.Start
                If rng.Information(wdWithInTable) Then
                    If c Is Nothing Then
                        Set c = rng.Cells(1)
                        s = c.Range.Start
                        rngDel.SetRange s, e
                        rngDel.Text = vbNullString
                    Else
                        'If c Is rng.Cells(1) Then 'in the same cell  more than one instance
                        If c.RowIndex = rng.Cells(1).RowIndex And c.ColumnIndex = rng.Cells(1).ColumnIndex Then 'in the same cell  more than one instance
                            rngDel.SetRange s, e
                            rngDel.Text = ","
                        Else
                            Set c = rng.Cells(1)
                            s = c.Range.Start
                            rngDel.SetRange s, e
                            rngDel.Text = vbNullString
                        End If
                    End If
                End If
                
            End If
            If rng.Characters(1) = "," And rng.Characters(2) = "[" Then
                rng.Characters(2) = vbNullString
            Else
                rng.Characters(1) = vbNullString
            End If
            rng.Characters(rng.Characters.Count) = vbNullString
            s = rng.End
            Set rngPre = rng.Duplicate
        Wend
        d.Range(rng.End, d.Range.End - 1).Text = vbNullString
    End With
    ur.EndCustomRecord

End Sub
```

Comment: No because I have a complex table in a Word document and I am not able to move it to another editor where I can run regex. It has to be wildcard. And yes I have to keep the original document format.

Comment: I tried your code. This keeps the brackets. I only want to keep what is between the brackets. Not the brackets themselves.

Comment: @misaligar `I have to keep the original document format.` `have a complex table` You didn't mention in your question. So you want to clear the word not table, you said `any character`, In practice, formatting marks such as tables are made of characters.Would you mind attaching a simple source sample and hopeful effect result for us to test?

Comment: My apologies for the confusion. I should have been more clear. Updated OP to clarify.

Comment: @misaligar OK, try my updated code to check it out thank you.